# Prism - how to test ShowDialogAsync (Extension method being called instead of class method)

Tags: c#, testing, prism, extension-methods

As we know, if there are method in a class and extension method with the same signature, the method in a class should be called instead of extension one.

So my problem is the next. I'm trying to mock `IDialogService` from `Prism.Services.Dialogs`. My goal is to have a mock for `ShowDialogAsync` method which could be tested (static/extensions methods couldn't be mocked).

The signature of `ShowDialogAsync` method is:

```
namespace Prism.Services.Dialogs
...
public static Task<IDialogResult> ShowDialogAsync(this IDialogService dialogService, 
   string name, IDialogParameters parameters = null);
```

So I created class `MockDialogService`:

```
namespace LoadApp.Core.Helpers
{
    public class MockDialogService : IDialogService
    {
        public void ShowDialog(string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<IDialogResult> ShowDialogAsync(string name, IDialogParameters parameters = null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ShowDialogAsync");
            IDialogResult res = new DialogResult();
            return Task.FromResult(res);
        }
    }

    public class DialogResult : IDialogResult
    {
        public Exception Exception { get; set; }
        public IDialogParameters Parameters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and use it in the test:

```
_dialogService = new MockDialogService();
...
var viewModel = new ViewModel(_dialogService);
```

During debug session I see `dialogService` in the model is the instance of my class `MockDialogService`. But `ShowDialogAsync` method from my class doesn't call, it is extension method still called. What I missed? Thank you in advance.

Comment: " if there are method in a class and extension method with the same signature, the method in a class should be called instead of extension one" - yes, if both were *in scope* at the time at which the call site was being compiled, at which point the C# compiler had to pick which specific method was being called and insert a token identifying that method into the IL. So, was your new `ShowDialogAsync` method in scope at the point at which the *call* to that method was compiled?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I think, yes, because of I have this namespace in my _using_ clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time I found the workaround.

I created my own extension method:

```
public static class MyDialogServiceExtensions
{
    public static Task<IDialogResult> ShowDialogAsync(this IDialogService dialogService, string name, IDialogParameters parameters = null)
    {
        if (dialogService is MockDialogService myService)
        {
            return myService.ShowDialogAsync(name, parameters);
        }
        return IDialogServiceExtensions.ShowDialogAsync(dialogService, name, parameters);
    }
}
```

and changed calls

```
await dialogService.ShowDialogAsync("MyDialogPage", parameters);
```

to

```
await MyDialogServiceExtensions.ShowDialogAsync(dialogService, "MyDialogPage", parameters);
```

P.S. I changed the question name to help others who have the same problem to find this topic.